# @Valid annotation is ignored with validating groups

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I have two beans:

```java
public class User {
    @NotNull
    public String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {Default.class, ChangeCheckGroup.class})
    public String password;

    @Valid
    public Details details;
}
```

and

```java
public class Details {
    @NotNull(groups = {Default.class, ChangeCheckGroup.class})
    public String email;
}
```

I am using **Hibernate Bean Validator** to manually validate *User* bean.

When i am trying to validate bean using no validating groups at all, it works as expected.

```java
Set<ConstraintViolation> cv = validator.validate( entitie );
```

It will check *user.name*, *user.password*, *user.details.email*.

But when i am trying to use validator with custom *ChangeCheckGroup* validating group, it ignores **@Valid** annotation.

```java
Set<ConstraintViolation> cv = validator.validate( entitie, groups );
```

Will check only *user.password*, and there will no check of an *user.details.email*.

Is there any way to validate bean and beans it holds using validating groups?

Comment: Your example works for me (email is validated with custom group). What version of hibernate-validator are you using?

Comment: did you check that details is not null in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in which your scenario could skip the inner validations for the Detail class would be that the User object has the details field set to null. The Validator would still consider the details null value as valid (since you did not specify a @NotNull annotation specifically for that field in any of the groups).

So, the Bean Validation annotations inside the Detail class will be ignored. Once you properly initialize the attribute details inside User, it will be validated according to the indicated group.

Comment: Yes, I must agree. It was my mistake, I did not set **@NotNull** on fields for which I want validation. Thank You.